# Why don't they use golf ball dimples on cars?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, drag, aerodynamics, turbulence

Just watched an episode of mythbusters where they proved that a car got better fuel economy with golf ball dimples. So why don't they use that on cars?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are vehicles not pitted like golf balls?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/192671/)