# Pressure in wake of turbulent vs laminar flow

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, turbulence

I understand that a turbulent flow creates a smaller wake than a laminar flow, as explained [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/197720/laminar-vs-turbulent-flow-separataion). Does the pressure inside this wake also depend on the flow regime (turbulent/laminar) or doesn't the wake *"know"* what kind of flow caused it?

Comment: Your question needs clarity. It's just hard to understand.

Comment: @lee is it more clear now?